# Angular directives. can I cancel a directive with a lower priority

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

lets say that I have an element with a couple of directives.
for example:

```
<div myFirstDirective='someFn'  mySecondDirective></div>
```

(myFirstDirective has a higher priority than mySecondDirective)

So, in this case, if myFirstDirective returns a false value from a function, I don't even want mySecondDirective to 'run'.
Is this even possible ?

If so, how would I 'cancel' the second directive ?

THanks for any insight

Comment: I wonder if another way might be to create a service that has both directive controllers injected in - then you could call the service in the main page controller and determine which directive to render. Unfortunately, I don't have a code example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need them to talk to each other by calling the other's controller.

```
app.directive('myFirstDirective', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'A', 
     priority: 20,
     controller: function ($scope) {
         var result = false;
         if ($scope.myFirstDirective) {
             result = $scope.myFirstDirective();
         }
         this.shouldRun = function() {
             return result;
         }
     },
     scope: { myFirstDirective: '&' }
  }
});

app.directive('mySecondDirective', function() {
  return {
     restrict: 'A', 
     priority: 10,
     require: '?myFirstDirective',
     link: function(scope, element, attr, otherController) {
         if(otherController && otherController.shouldRun()) {
             // execute this directive only if 
             // function from first directive returns true.
         }

     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just evaluate the result of myFirstDirective attribute in the mySecondDirective link function. If not the correct value is applied you immediately quit the link function.

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    //link of mySecondDirective
    var firstValue = scope.$eval(attributes.myFirstDirective);
    if (!firstValue) return;

    // else do some cool stuff
}
```

Comment: wow, these are both clever solutions, thanks! ideally I don't want the second directive to have any 'dependency' or know about the first, but this opens up some more ideas for me : )

Comment: Your accepted answer has also a dependency on the the directive.